# Modelling of a flow network with a positional constraint

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, network-flow

While I do realise pasting an exercise question in here is not exactly perfect form, I am desperate and I wil try anyway. So here it goes:

Consider a set of n mobile computing clients in a town with k mobile base stations. Every client needs to be connected to one exactly one base station. Each of the n clients as well as each of the k base stations is speciﬁed by its (x,y) coordinates in the plane. Each client needs to be connected to exactly one base station. For a given parameter r, a client can only be connected to a base station that is within distance r from the client. At the same time, no base station can handle more than L clients being assigned to it. Design a polynomial-time algorithm for the following problem: Given the positions of the n clients and k base stations, as well as the range and load parameters r and L, respectively, decide whether all clients can be connected to the base stations, subject to the range and load conditions as described above. Argue that your algorithm is correct.

I understand that I have to use Max-Flow theory somehow, and I am guessing the flow network would be a bipartite graph with a constraint on the degrees of one of the two partitions to be <= L. But how do I model a positional variable like r into it? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: $r$ is there to limit which edges between clients and stations are available. If $\mathrm{dist}(c_i,s_j)\leq r$, then the edge $(c_i,s_j)$ belongs to the graph. ($c_i$ are the clients, $s_j$ the stations)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> While I do realise pasting an exercise question in here is not exactly perfect form, I am desperate and I wil try anyway.

I am a official tutor in algorithmic graph theory. I’ll save you. :-) We construct a usual flow model $\mathcal F$ for your problem as follows. Let $s$ and $t$ be a sourse and a target, respectively, of a flow network, $c_1,\dots, c_n$ be the clients, and $b_1,\dots, b_k$ be the base stations. Introduce edges $(s, c_1),\dots, (s, c_n)$ of capacity $1$ each and $(b_1,t),\dots, (b_k,t)$ of capacity $L$ each. Also introduce edges $(c_i,b_j)$ iff the distance between $c_i$ and $b_j$ is at most $r$. It is easy to check that all clients can be connected to the base stations, subject to the range and load conditions iff maxflow in $\mathcal F$ is $n$ (one way it is obvious, but the other way we use Integrality Theorem stating that if all capacities are integral, then there is an integral maximum flow). There are the [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FLUIn.png) polynomial-time algorithms to find a maxflow in $\mathcal F$.